# how do i access my php file uploaded to my own server?

Tags: server, ftp, cpanel

I have recently got access to a server where i created a database and uploaded a .php file successfully but now I cant access the .php file on browser as all I see on the browser looks more like the "phpmyadmin" than a "cpanel" with created databases but not the files uploaded through "filezilla"

Comment: are you try using "ssh" or "telnet"?

Comment: iam using ssh not telnet